# turn off autostart of Apache on Windows 7

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, zend

Zend server install of Apache & PHP mysql starts servers at each reboot of Windows 7 PC.
How can I turn this off?

Now I have to run `ApacheMonitor.exe` from `C:\zend_server\Apache2\bin`

I checked:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

and I turned it off in `msconfig.exe` + startup

but it keeps coming back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have been installed as services.

Open services.msc (search for it in the start menu search field, or open control panel -> administrative tools -> services)

The services may theoretically be named anything, but likely bets are to look for names starting with Apache, httpd, Zend and MySQL. When you identify one, open its properties and set it to manual or disabled.

Comment: great answer Erike!  Why do people downvote honest & researched questions.  They add nothing to the discussion and drive people elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks itp and welcome here! Personally I would think it good courtesy to leave some form of explanation for a downvote, to encourage and guide to what would pass as higher quality or relevance in that persons eye. You and I are left guessing, and this may have an unneccessarily alienating side effect. But that's just me, a very new member here. The two help pages I find: http://serverfault.com/help/why-vote and http://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: Btw I might as well be clear. I have set my own standard to upvote for researched, well phrased, relevant questions. I never downvote attempts to help, but only answers which are identifiable as directly harmful. The comment field together with the moderators I find to be more powerful tools than question downvoting. But others think differently. This being an explicitly communitydriven site is more important in my eyes than limiting the opinion spread which comes with that territory.